# Should namenode memory usage count replicated or unreplicated blocks

Tags: hadoop

Many sources describe how to calculate the amount of memory needed of the Hadoop Namenode.
Two rules-of-thumb are often quoted, (1) about 150 bytes per object or (2) about a million objects per Gb RAM. Disregarding the obvious discrepancy between these two numbers (i.e. 1 Gb/150b ~ 7 million, not 1 million), my question is regarding the first suggestion.
Should the number of blocks be counted including their replication or not?

In other words, running hadoop fsck -blocks / gives me 670000 blocks.
Should I then calculate required RAM as 150*670000 or 150*670000*3 (we have the default replication factor of 3).

/Thomas